# How to create a react and stylus compiler?

Tags: reactjs, npm, stylus, gulp-stylus

Right now I'm trying to create the above compiler using npm and gulp. But I keep getting stuck. 
I only need it to compile jsx and stylus files to run on a localhost server.

Comment: This is not 'creat[ing] a compiler', and it has nothing whatsoever to do with [tag:compiler-construction]. It is nothing more complex than writing a simple shell script.

Answer (score 0):

In your webpack config, Add loader for jsx and stylus like below code.

**For JSX & Stylus:**

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.styl$/,
        loader: 'css-loader!stylus-relative-loader?paths=node_modules/bootstrap-stylus/stylus/'
      }
    ]
  },
```